# Cross Product for functions

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, cross-product

So functions are just uncountabley-infinite dimensional vectors, and as such there's a nice generalization of the inner product between two functions (the integral of their product).  Is their a similar generalization for the cross product between two functions?!

Comment: Normally the cross product is only well-defined in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: @DanRust that's not true, it is also defined in $\mathbb{R}^7$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thinking of functions as uncountably-infinite vectors may lead you wildly astray, so I'd be careful of that.

The cross product is a fairly unique binary operation, as it turns out.  For any vector space $V$, we have an inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle:V\times V\to \mathbb R$ (we're just going to assume these are real vector spaces). However, in most circumstances we DO NOT have an operation from $V\times V\to V$.  The notable exceptions are the cross product in $\mathbb R^3$ and $\mathbb R^7$ (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-dimensional_cross_product)).

You can lift the idea of an inner product to functions, though. Have you had any functional analysis? If you haven't this idea may be a little hard to tackle.

Comment: neat.  R3 and R7, I had no idea. All my functional analysis is of the arm-chair variety.  I am comfortable with the functional inner product though.  But I thought it would be cool to have an operation that takes two functions and returns one orthogonal to both, like a cross product does.  No go?

Comment: I'm afraid no go. While there are many functions orthogonal to two other functions, there isn't a way to do it uniquely.